# Trigonometric expression manipulation

Tags: trigonometry

I'm working on manipulating trig expressions using Khan Academy.

According to the provided answer this:

$$\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$$

is supposed to equal:

$$\frac1 2\sin(2\theta)$$

I do not understand how, so could someone please show me.

​

Comment: Do you wnt a proof that $\sin (2x)=2\sin x \cos x$ ?

Comment: sin(2x) = sin(x+x) = ... use the addition formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $\sin (x + y) =\sin (x) \cdot \cos (y) +\cos (x) \cdot \sin (y) $

What happens when $x=y$ ?

Comment: Which begs the question: where does the first formula come from?

Comment: The practice session of manipulating trig expressions on KA comes  after the exposure to the principal identities in question.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the Law of Sines on the following diagram.

[image]

Hint 2:  $\cos x = \sin(90^\circ - x)$

Comment: I do not understand this

Comment: That's unfortunate, because it is reasonably straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

It is an immediate consequence of the double angle formula
$$
\sin (2 \theta)= 2 \sin \theta \cos  \theta
$$

This formula is found, for $\alpha=\beta=\theta$ from the sum formula:
$$
\sin (\alpha+\beta)=\sin \alpha \cos \beta+ \cos\alpha \cos \beta
$$and you can find a proof of this one [here](http://www.themathpage.com/atrig/sum-proof.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Using complex numbers, in particular $e^{i\theta} = cos(\theta) + isen(\theta)$

Using the change of variable: $\theta = 2\phi$

Whe have,    $e^{i(2\phi)} = cos(2\phi) + isen(2\phi)$

And as $e^{i(2\phi)} = (e^{i\phi})^2 = (cos(\phi) + isen(\phi))^2 = cos^2(\phi) - sen^2(\phi) + i(2cos(\phi)sen(\phi))$

Then, $cos(2\phi) + isen(2\phi) = cos^2(\phi) - sen^2(\phi) + i(2cos(\phi)sen(\phi))$

Finally equalling real and imaginary parts:

$cos(2\phi) = cos^2(\phi) - sen^2(\phi)$

And

$sen(2\phi) = 2cos(\phi)sen(\phi)$

Which is what we where looking for.

Answer (score -2):

$(e^{ia})^2    =  e^{2ia}.$

L.H.S   =  $( cos^2(a)   - sin^2(a) , 2sin(a).cos(a))$

R.H.S  =   $(cos(2a) , sin(2a))$